# Inform Visual Studio to ignore folder in a project directory

Tags: python, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to create a VS project/solution from a folder containing python files, a data folder.

The data folder is very large and contains a lot of files (Gigs of gray scale images). I've had trouble creating a new project using `create from existing python code` and I resorted to manually creating the `.sln` and `.pyproj` files (Created an empty project and ported over the created files).

I still can't open my solution. While some files and code appear on the screen when I try to load this project. VS does not respond to any action. I assume this is because it's trying to load in all the images in this folder.

Is there a way to tell Visual Studio to ignore this folder when loading in this project?

While writing this post the project finally loaded to a point where I could use VS. But it didn't load any of the files in the solution explorer other than the default files from the empty project I created to port over the `.sln` and `.pyproj` files. I unloaded the project and when I reloaded it the same initial issue reappeared (very very slow loading to the point of no response).

Comment: Try in Solution Explorer to right-click on the folder and select *Exclude from Project*. If the option is not available, you may need to select the files in the folder for that,

Comment: Maybe do to me porting over the pyproj and sln files. Nothing other than the initial files created by the empty project (then one I used to generate these files before porting them over) appears in the solution explorer.